# Mongodb does not perform update of document after updating only part of a document's field

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I'm using spring boot version 1.4.2 and mongodb 3.4.2

When I use the repository interface to persist an already existing document after making a change to one of the properties of the document, the old document gets saved. For example:

```java
@Document(collection="UserDoc)
public class UserDoc{
@Id
private String id;    
private String userName;
private String passWord;
private int age;
//getters and setters...
}
@Autowired
private UserDocRepository userDocRepository;
UserDoc userDoc = userDocRepository.findOne("dummyId");
//assume the id passed in is correct and a UserDoc is returned.
//now when i change one of the fields,eg the age and save it back,the old 
//value gets persisted,eg if age is 10 and i change it to 5,the old property  
//is still persisted to db unless i Create a new UserDoc and copy all the 
//properties before it gets persisted with the correct value of 5.
userDoc.setAge(5);
userDocRepository.save(userDoc);//this is supposed to update the document 
//with a new value of 5 instead of 10 as it was probably per the assumption.

UserDoc userDocUpdated = new UserDoc();
userDocUpdated.setId(userDoc.getId);
userDocUpdated.setUserName(userDoc.getUserName);
userDocUpdated.setPassWord(userDoc.getPassWord);
userDocUpdated.setAge(5); //this way,the document is updated with 5 as the 
//age

userDocRepository.save(userDocUpdated);//this updates it accordingly with 
//the desired value of 5 for the age
```

What could be the problem with the first scenario?Could it be a problem with mongodb or spring boot?Any insights will be gladly appreciated.

Comment: check the second time you call "userRepository", should be userRepository.save(userDoc);

Comment: @PaoloMangia,i don't get you, can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

sadly i know so little about java but,

this is what you are doing:

```
private UserDocRepository userDocRepository;
UserDoc userDoc = userRepository.findOne("dummyId");
userDocRepository.save(userDoc);//this is supposed to update the document
```

and this is what i think you should do this instead:

```
private UserDocRepository userDocRepository;
UserDoc userDoc = userDocRepository.findOne("dummyId");
userDocRepository.save(userDoc);//this is supposed to update the document
```

correct me if i'm wrong :)

Comment: You are right,but that is just a typo,that is not the main issue here.The main issue is the setters on the retrieved object from the database does not reflect when persisted to the db without making a clone of the retrieved object before setting new values.Thanks.